# How do I create a temp table using this snippet?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

how do i produce this SQL snippet as a temp table so I can join some other stuff into it?

```
with MyCTE AS
(
    select *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY workplace ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Rank
    from [dbo].[OriginDestination]
)
select * from MyCTE where Rank <= 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
with MyCTE AS
(
    select *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY workplace ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Rank
    from [dbo].[OriginDestination]
)
select *
into #yourTempTable 
from MyCTE 
where Rank <= 5
```